# Google app script,gmail addon get TextInput value

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have create simple gmail addon using google script,in that i have struggle here,

how to get textinput value when we perform some action,i have checked the document, i couldn't find any methods

[TextInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input)

The below code i have tried,

```
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Login Here"));
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
  var cleint_id_Input = CardService.newTextInput()
     .setFieldName("client_id")
     .setTitle("Please enter clinet id")
  var username_Input = CardService.newTextInput()
     .setFieldName("username")
     .setTitle("Please enter username")
  var password_Input = CardService.newTextInput()
     .setFieldName("password")
     .setTitle("Please enter password")
  section.addWidget(cleint_id_Input)
  section.addWidget(username_Input)
  section.addWidget(password_Input)
  Logger.log("Input Value%s",cleint_id_Input)
  //Login action button
  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('loginCallback');
  section.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Login').setOnClickAction(action))  
  card.addSection(section)
```

i need inputText value in "loginCallback" function

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can retrieve the inputted values as JSON object. The modified script retrieves the inputted values and displays them. So please modify this for your environment.

### Modified script :

```
function buildAddOn() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Login Here"));
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
  var cleint_id_Input = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("client_id")
    .setTitle("Please enter clinet id")
  var username_Input = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("username")
    .setTitle("Please enter username")
  var password_Input = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("password")
    .setTitle("Please enter password")
  section.addWidget(cleint_id_Input)
  section.addWidget(username_Input)
  section.addWidget(password_Input)
  Logger.log("Input Value%s",cleint_id_Input)
  //Login action button
  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('loginCallback');
  section.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Login').setOnClickAction(action))  
  card.addSection(section)
  return card.build() // Added
}

// Added
function loginCallback(e) {
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('sample'))
  .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(
    CardService.newKeyValue().setContent(JSON.stringify(e.formInput, null, "  ")))
  )
  .build();
}
```

### Inputted values :

In your case, `e` of `loginCallback(e)` is as follows.

```
{
    "formInput": {
        "password": "###",
        "client_id": "###",
        "username": "###"
    },
    "clientPlatform": "web",
    "messageMetadata": {
        "messageId": "###",
        "accessToken": "###"
    },
    "formInputs": {
        "password": [
            "###"
        ],
        "client_id": [
            "###"
        ],
        "username": [
            "###"
        ]
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: i have small query, how open add on when open email,without click addon icon

Comment: @Robert I think that is not small query for me. I'm sorry. I don't have the solution about it yet. When I have it, I will let you know.

Comment: @Robert I'm really sorry. By the way, I commented to your other question. Can I get your reply for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561117/google-apps-script-handle-global-variable-for-gmail-add-on#comment84391098_48561117

Comment: did you know answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/q/48705997/7261317

Comment: @Robert I saw it. But I cannot understand what you want to do. I'm sorry. When users inputted a text using ``newTextInput()``, do you want to change the value?

Comment: Yes,we need to change "setOnChangeAction" of callback function for that  "newTextInput()"

Comment: @Robert Do you want to change the callback functions by the inputted text?

Comment: @Robert For example, when an user inputted the text of "A", you want to run "functionA". When the user inputted the text of "B", you want to run "functionB". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: NO,consider this,we have newTextInput().setOnChangeAction('functionA'). then we need change input value in "functionA"

Comment: @Robert I'm sorry. I cannot image the vision what you want. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Robert Do you want to change the inputted text which is displaying in the text box?

Comment: Yes We need to change

Comment: @Robert ok. I could understand it. Can I have the time to think of it? When I find the solution or workaround, I will tell you.

Comment: Please let me know,i waiting for inputs