# Google script gmail addon update TextInput value,on change function

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have create simple gmail addon using google script,in that i have struggle here,

how to update textinput value on **setOnChangeAction** Method ,i have checked the document, i couldn't find any methods

The below code i have tried,

```
var client_action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('clientId_callBack');
CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName("clientId")
  .setTitle("Please enter clinet id")
  .setOnChangeAction(client_action)

function clientId_callBack(e){
  Logger.log("%s",JSON.stringify(e))
  e.formInput.clientId = "updatedValue";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow the sample in [Class SelectionInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input). Based on the sample, you're supposed to place a function inside that triggers when ChangeAction happens. setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
         .setFunctionName("handleCheckboxChange"));

Answer (score 0):

How about this work around? I think that there may be other ways. So please think of this as one of several answers. In this sample script, when the value of `foo` is inputted, the text input is reconstructed using CardBuilder. When you use this script, as a test, please input `foo`. This is a very simple snippet, so please modify this for your environment.

#### Sample script :

```
function buildAddOn() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Sample"));
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('changeValue');
  section.addWidget(CardService.newTextInput().setFieldName("value").setTitle("Input \"foo\" as a value.").setOnChangeAction(action))
  return card.addSection(section).build()
}

function changeValue(e) {
  if (e.formInput.value == "foo") {
    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
    card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Changed"));
    var section = CardService.newCardSection();
    var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('getValue1');
    section.addWidget(CardService.newTextInput().setFieldName("value").setTitle("Got \"foo\".").setOnChangeAction(action).setValue("bar"))
    return card.addSection(section).build()
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.