# Password input type in google calendar add-on using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api, gsuite-addons

I am developing google calendar add-on using `CardService`, Is there any method available for adding password input box in calendar add-on using apps script.

For other google services, It can be added using `HTML Service` and by using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` like method, for calendar `.getUi()` does not seem to be available.

Does anyone have an idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, between the methods supported for the [Card Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service) class there's no way to create a password input, the most similar one would be the [TextInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input) class.

#### Workaround 1:

Use a [TextButton](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button) to open a link in another window where you could have an application with the password input (e.g a link to a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)).

#### Workaround 2:

Using an onChangeAction from the TextInput to manipulate the value from the text input and return the card element again to the user (as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727649/11352221)). This would involve having to store the updated value from the text input, using the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) for example, and changing the value of the text input to the same number of character the user has typed but replacing the characters with '*'.